# How can I optimize email sending time in Django using Redis pub/sub and multithreading?

Tags: django, multithreading, optimization, redis, publish-subscribe

## Django: Optimizing the sending time by using pub-sub with multiple threads dispatching emails in parallel.

Repository link: [EmailCampaignManager](https://github.com/krish-patel1003/EmailCampaignManager)
(Checkout the pub/sub branch)

.campaigns/views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from campaigns.serializers import EmailCampaignSerializer
import redis
# Create your views here.

class EmailCampaignView(APIView):

    red = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=49153, decode_responses=True, password="redispw")

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = EmailCampaignSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(
                {"data": serializer.data, "message": "Campaign Created Successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response({"error": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


def publish_email_campaign(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    red = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=49153, decode_responses=True, password="redispw")
    red.publish('email_campaign', str(instance.id))
    print(f"message published on email_campaign channel, message={str(instance.id)}")
```

.campaigns/signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from campaigns.models import EmailCampaign
from campaigns.email_dispatcher import send_emails
from campaigns.views import publish_email_campaign
import redis
import threading

@receiver(post_save, sender=EmailCampaign, dispatch_uid="email_campaign_created")
def send_email_campaigns(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    publish_email_campaign(sender, instance, **kwargs)

    red = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=49153, decode_responses=True, password="redispw")
    sub = red.pubsub()
    sub.subscribe('email_campaign')
    print("subscribed to email_campaign channel, listening for messages")
    for message in sub.listen():
        campaign_id = message.get('data')
        print(f"message received on email_campaign channel, message={campaign_id}")
        if campaign_id == str(instance.id):
            campaign = EmailCampaign.objects.get(id=campaign_id)
            send_emails(campaign)
```

./campaigns/email_dispatcher.py

```
from subscribers.models import Subscriber
import threading
from campaigns.utils import render_email_template, send_email


def process_email(event, campaign, subscriber):

    email_content = render_email_template(campaign, subscriber)
    
    retries = 3  # Number of retries
    while retries > 0:
        try:
            print(f"trying to send email, {campaign.subject} to {subscriber.email}")
            send_email(campaign, subscriber, email_content)
            print(f"email sent, {campaign.subject} to {subscriber.email}")
            event.set() # Signal that the thread is completed
            return  # Email sent successfully, exit the loop
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to send email: {str(e)}")
            retries -= 1

    print(f"Max retries exceeded for email: {campaign.subject} to {subscriber.email}")


def send_emails(campaign):

    subscribers = Subscriber.objects.filter(active=True)
    threads = []
    event = threading.Event()

    # Create threads for processing emails
    for subscriber in subscribers:
        print(f"processing email thread, {campaign.subject} to {subscriber.email}")
        thread = threading.Thread(
            target=process_email, 
            args=(event, campaign, subscriber)
        )
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
        print(f"email thread started, {campaign.subject} to {subscriber.email}")

    # Wait for all the threads to complete
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    event.wait() # Wait until all the threads are completed
```

./campaigns/utils.py

```
from django.core import mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from smtplib import SMTPException  



def render_email_template(campaign, subscriber):
    
    email_content = {
        'html_message': render_to_string('campaigns/email_campaign_template.html', {'campaign': campaign, 'subscriber': subscriber}),
        'plain_message': campaign.plain_text_content,
    }

    return email_content


def send_email(campaign, subscriber, email_content):

    try:
        mail.send_mail(
            subject=campaign.subject,
            message=email_content["plain_message"],
            from_email="gujjubkc01@gmail.com",
            recipient_list=[subscriber.email],
            html_message=email_content["html_message"],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        return 
    except SMTPException as e:          
        print('There was an SMTP error sending an email.'+ str(e))

    except Exception as e:
        print('There was an error sending an email.'+ str(e))
```

I am trying to make a email_dispatcher using redis pub/sub and multithreading to optimize the email sending time.

There are 2 issues.[issues](https://github.com/krish-patel1003/EmailCampaignManager/issues)

1. pub/sub: Incorrect message listening: The message published on "email_campaign" channel is not properly listened on the subscriber end. The subscriber always listens to message with {"data": 1}.
2. send_email function failing silently:

- The "send_email" function in ./campaigns/utils.py is failing silently though it is configured with fail_silently=False.
- Due to which threading runs into a infinite loop.
- Resulting in no response to emailcampaign post request.

I need help solving the issues and if possible also a another better solution to optimize email sending time using pub/sub model and multi-threading.